# Post an HTML Input with datetime Value to MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am looking for a solution to capturing a users input from a HTML input set to a value of 'datetime-local' into a MySQL database with a table field set to 'datetime'. Whenever I submit the form an ID is generated and the date is saved, but the time is not. EX: 2018-11-20 00:00:00.

My HTML:

```
<form class="" action="/index.php" method="post">
  <input type="datetime-local" name="myDate" id="myDate"><br /><br />
  <button id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button><br /><br />
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
// Check Our Connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
  die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// Insert Our Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_one ( mydate ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['myDate'])}' )";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

// Print Response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
  echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
} else {
  die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}

// Close Connection
$mysqli->close();
```

I got the code from a tutorial on Youtube, and it is working so far. I just want to be able to get the time that they select as well.

UPDATE:
The time is being saved, but it appears to be in military time. EX: Input = 11/22/2018 5:00 PM ; Output = 2018-11-22 17:00:00

UPDATE AFTER FIRST COMMENT:
This directs me to a failed HTTP request -

```
  // Check Our Connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }

  // Insert Our Data
  $date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime(real_escape_string($_POST['myDate'])));
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test_one ( mydate ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['$date'])}' )";
  $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

  // Print Response from MySQL
  if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
  } else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
  }

  // Close Connection
  $mysqli->close();
```

If it has anything to do with ' ' around $date I have tried it without and got the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [datetime-local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) adds a T in the middle, i.e. 2018-11-19T10:52:23. You have to change the format to remove the T. Maybe try this:

```
$date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', strtotime(real_escape_string($_POST['myDate'])));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. Thank you though! I placed it above the $sql line then update the $_POST after the VALUE to capture $date, but after I submitted the form I got an HTTP error. @miken32

Comment: @EataSandwhich Did you use it as $_POST['date']? As that won't work it would need to be just $date. i.e. VALUES ($date)

Comment: Ill update my question to include the new code @Dan W.

Comment: @EataSandwhich The time 'military time' is how servers treat datetime, you have to convert it back after you pull it out of the database.

Comment: Oh.... ok. so I guess I am good with that then, right? If you can't tell I am an expert at this hahah @Dan W.